# Array updation in ruby

Tags: ruby

Given two arrays:

```
s1 = ["Arun#2#very good shop","Mani#4#i am very glad to meet you sir.","Anu#2#not bad"]
s2 = ["first","second","third"]
```

I want a new array `s3` like:

```
s3 = ["Arun#2#very good shop#first","Mani#4#i am very glad to meet you sir#second.","Anu#2#not bad#third"]
```

Comment: Thanks all fro ur quick response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
> s3 = [s1,s2].transpose.map{|a| a.join("#")}
 => ["Arun#2#very good shop#first", "Mani#4#i am very glad to meet you sir.#second", "Anu#2#not bad#third"]
```

**Note:** This will work if two array has same number of elements.

**Alternative Option** : this will work for any number of elements in two array

```
> s1.zip(["#"].cycle, s2).map(&:join)
 => ["Arun#2#very good shop#first", "Mani#4#i am very glad to meet you sir.#second", "Anu#2#not bad#third"]
```

Comment: Note that this solution fails if the size of the arrays are different.

Comment: @Drenmi : Thanks, I have updated Note and Alternative

Answer (score 8):

```
s3 = s1.zip(s2).map{ |x| x.join('#')}
=> ["Arun#2#very good shop#first", "Mani#4#i am very glad to meet you sir.#second", "Anu#2#not bad#third"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to append elements of `s2` to `s1` at corresponding index after `#`:

```
s3 = []
s1.each_with_index{|a, i| s3 << a + "#" + s2[i].to_s}
s3
# => ["Arun#2#very good shop#first", "Mani#4#i am very glad to meet you sir.#second", "Anu#2#not bad#third"]
```